# Sort numpy array

Tags: arrays, numpy, detection, box

I try to sort numpy array but have no idea how to do it so that my detection works:
[console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CjEo8.png)
[snippet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vTvH3.png)

however I need to sort only from [0:4] - bounding boxes to achieve the detection from left to right.

EDIT: Code with i use:

```
`for output in layer_outs:
    for detection in output:
        
        scores = detection[5:]
        class_id = np.argmax(scores)
        confidence = scores[class_id]

        if confidence > CONFIDENCE_THRESHOLD:
            box = detection[0:4] * np.array([W, H, W, H])
            (center_x, center_y, width, height) = box.astype("int")

            x = int(center_x - (width / 2))
            y = int(center_y - (height / 2))

            boxes.append([x, y, int(width), int(height)])
            confidences.append(float(confidence))
            class_ids.append(class_id)
            

idxs = cv2.dnn.NMSBoxes(boxes, confidences, CONFIDENCE_THRESHOLD, NMS_THRESHOLD)

if len(idxs) > 0:
    for i in idxs.flatten():
        (x, y) = (boxes[i][0], boxes[i][1])
        (w, h) = (boxes[i][2], boxes[i][3])
        
        
        color = [int(c) for c in COLORS[class_ids[i]]]
        bbx(image, (x,y), (x+w, y+h), color, thickness_bbox)
        text_print = "{}: {:.1f}".format(lbls[class_ids[i]], confidences[i]*100)
        text = "{}".format(lbls[class_ids[i]])
        cv2.putText(image, text, (x, y +h - 5), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.5, color, 2)
        
        print(text)`
```

my array from console:

to be sorted

[9.5494914e-01 9.0752786e-01 7.2654195e-02 2.0772834e-01 7.0289302e-06
0.0000000e+00 0.0000000e+00 0.0000000e+00 0.0000000e+00 0.0000000e+00
0.0000000e+00 0.0000000e+00 0.0000000e+00 0.0000000e+00 0.0000000e+00]

to be sorted

[9.5296764e-01 8.9935684e-01 1.1596789e-01 6.2234199e-01 1.8487071e-06
0.0000000e+00 0.0000000e+00 0.0000000e+00 0.0000000e+00 0.0000000e+00
0.0000000e+00 0.0000000e+00 0.0000000e+00 0.0000000e+00 0.0000000e+00]

to sort results according first four arguments in array:

```
9
8
1
5
```

Comment: Please add the your source array as **text**. We have no time to rewrite numbers from your pictures. Put also the expected result.

Comment: Sorry. I've edited my post with source code.